# Batch file to Create Folders with variable prefix

Tags: batch-file, directory, prefix

I am trying to create folders in batch with Prefix where the prefix is project's name. I don't know what is the best way to achieve the result as below. Thanks in advance. Example Bellow:

**Project's name = Project 1**

```
project-1_export\project-1_DWG  
project-1_export\project-1_IMAGES 
project-1_export\project-1_PDF 
project-1_export\project-1_ZIP 
project-1_LIBRARY 
project-1_SUPPORT DOCUMENTS\project-1_Scans 
project-1_SUPPORT DOCUMENTS\project-1_PDF\project-1_Client 
project-1_SUPPORT DOCUMENTS\project-1_PDF\project-1_Others
```

**Project's name = Project 2**

```
project-2_export\project-2_DWG  
project-2_export\project-2_IMAGES 
project-2_export\project-2_PDF 
project-2_export\project-2_ZIP 
project-2_LIBRARY 
project-2_SUPPORT DOCUMENTS\project-2_Scans 
project-2_SUPPORT DOCUMENTS\project-2_PDF\project-2_Client 
project-2_SUPPORT DOCUMENTS\project-2_PDF\project-2_Others
```

**This is my attempt after browsing the resource here.**

```
@echo off
set /p id= Enter Project ID?
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (file.txt) do (
mkdir %id%_"%%a"
)
```

where 'file.txt' contains a list of name of the folders and subfolders.
and Project ID is Project 1/2/3

**My questions are**

I have no problem using the text file to create folders, but I don't know how to use it to create subfolder. Is it possible?

If yes, how to put the project id prefix in front the subfolder's name?

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. [SO] isn't a free script writing service. Own research and code attempts are expected. [Edit] the question to include **your** code in a [mcve].

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: Hi, I did try, but I cannot get it working. Maybe I did something wrong. Where to put Createproject 1234? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Going by your folders, I assume you want to rename all the files in the tree based on the main `project#` directory. Going by an example tree bellow:

```
C:\MainFolder
├───project1
│   ├───export
│   │   ├───DWG
│   │   ├───Images
│   │   ├───PDF
│   │   └───ZIP
│   └───support documents
└───project2
    ├───export
    │   ├───DWG
    │   ├───Images
    │   ├───PDF
    │   └───ZIP
    └───support documents
```

We can use a series of `for` loops to gather information about each folder using `dir "Path\*" /b /s /a:d`. This will allow us to get each folder from the respected `MainDir` --> `ProjectX`. From here we simply rename the tree from after this `ProjectX` folder to the `ProjectX_OriginalFolderName` format. This will give us our new respective tree bellow.

```
C:\MainFolder
├───project1
│   ├───project1_export
│   │   ├───project1_DWG
│   │   ├───project1_Images
│   │   ├───project1_PDF
│   │   └───project1_ZIP
│   └───project1_support documents
└───project2
    ├───project2_export
    │   ├───project2_DWG
    │   ├───project2_Images
    │   ├───project2_PDF
    │   └───project2_ZIP
    └───project2_support documents
```

The script bellow should solve all your issues. Please take a look at each `Rem | Note` for more information on each process in the script. Furthermore, you will want to change `Set "MainDir=C:\MainFolderLocation"` to your respected directory containing `project#` folders.

As an added safety, I also added a `Set "MustContain=project"` so this way the script will only modify file tree's who's `project#` contains `project`. If you have other folders in this directory (`C:\MainFolderLocation`) the those not containing project will not be touched. If this is not what you want and you wish to tweak absolutely everything in this directory then remove the `Rem | Check If Current Folder Contains ProjectX` for loop.

**EditFolderTree.bat:**

```
@ECHO OFF
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Rem | Configuration
Set "MainDir=C:\MainFolderLocation"
Set "MustContain=project"

Rem | Get Each Project Folder
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir "!MainDir!\" /b /a:d') do (

    Set "MainFolder=%%~nA"

    Rem | Check If Current Folder Contains ProjectX
    for /f "tokens=*" %%B in ('echo !MainFolder!^| find /I "!MustContain!"') do (

        Set "BaseFolderName=%%~nB"

        Rem | Get Each Folder In ProjectX Dir
        for /f "tokens=*" %%C in ('dir "!MainDir!\!BaseFolderName!\*" /b /s /a:d') do (

            Set "FolderName=%%C"

            Rem | Check If Current Folder Already has ProjectX_
            for /f "tokens=*" %%D in ('echo !FolderName!^| find /V "!BaseFolderName!_"') do (

                Rem | Save Results To File
                Echo %%D >> DataFile.temp

            )

        )

    )

)

Rem | Check If DataFile.temp Exists
If exist "%~dp0DataFile.temp" (

    Rem | Reverse Tree From TextFile
    for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (DataFile.temp) do (
        set /A I=!I! + 1
        set LINE!I!=%%A
    )
    Del %~dp0DataFile.temp
    for /L %%A in (!I!,-1,1) do (

        echo !LINE%%A! >> DataFile.temp

    )

    Rem | Read TextFile & Get Paths
    for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (DataFile.temp) do (

        Set "FolderName=%%~nA"

        Rem | Get project Number
        Set "String=%%A"
        Set "String=!String:%MainDir%\=!"
        for /F "tokens=1,2* delims=\" %%B in ('Echo !String!') do (

            Set "BaseFolderName=%%B"

        )

        Rem | Rename Folders
        CD "%%A\.."
        rename "!FolderName!" "!BaseFolderName!_!FolderName!"

    )
    Del %~dp0DataFile.temp

)
goto :EOF
```

---

For help on any of the commands do the following:

- `call /?`
- `set /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `find /?`
- So on.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am absolutely new to this. I will take me a while to go through your script.

Comment: @Alan Diffidently, take your time. Please let me know any feedback you have and don't feel shy to make a test directory so you can "Test" the script - to see if it fits your needs.

Comment: No, I actually I want to create new folder structures for new projects, not renaming it. But really thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**CreateProject.bat**

```
@echo off
if "%~1" == "" goto :help
md "project-%~1_export\project-%~1_DWG  
md "project-%~1_export\project-%~1_IMAGES 
md "project-%~1_export\project-%~1_PDF 
md "project-%~1_export\project-%~1_ZIP 
md "project-%~1_LIBRARY 
md "project-%~1_SUPPORT DOCUMENTS\project-%~1_Scans 
md "project-%~1_SUPPORT DOCUMENTS\project-%~1_PDF\project-%~1_Client 
md "project-%~1_SUPPORT DOCUMENTS\project-%~1_PDF\project-%~1_Others 
goto :eof
:help
echo to create the folderstructure for a project 1, type:
echo %~n0 1
```

Call it with the project number (or name?) as a parameter:

```
createproject 1234
```

Comment: I cannot get it working. Maybe I did something wrong. Where to put Createproject 1234? Thanks.

Comment: put `createproject.bat` into the main folder and execute it (from command line) with `createproject 5`, where 5 is your desired project id.

Comment: Get it working on command line finally. Although it is not exactly how I want it, I will study it further and adapt something to suit my situation. thanks.again.